# Foursquare users/self endpoint returning incorrect friends count

Tags: api, foursquare

Currently the user/self returns a friends block for my account with a count of 10, while the users/self/friends returns a count of 65.

Typically the "count" value represents the total number of elements in the set not just the number of elements returned.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: This isn't a known issue and your description of the expected behavior is correct. Can you email api (at) foursquare (dot) com with your Foursquare user ID? We can take this offline to figure out the root of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been resolved by the foursquare api team.